# 403 Authentication credentials not provided on request with Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, authentication, alamofire

I am getting a 403 on a a get request with Alamofire. Error message I get from server is: Authentication Credentials Not Provided.
Have been following this issue of missing authentication headers in request. I am sure I send my access token in the authentication header. WireShark shows that the request is sent out with the auth header. So I am not sure how to fix that. Here is the code snippet:

```
 var authenticatedJsonHeaders: [String: String] {
        get {
            return [
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "Accept": "application/json",
                "Authorization": "\(accessTokenAuthType.rawValue) \(accessTokenString)"
            ]
        }
    }

.....

return Alamofire.request(urlString, method:method, parameters: nil, encoding: encoding, headers: authenticatedJsonHeaders)
        .response { response in

            let currentUserId = ApplicationState.sharedInstance.currentUserManager.getCurrentUserProfileId()

            if(currentUserId == 0){ //if current user exists, do not sign the user out!
                print("bye user..")
                self.signOutUnauthorizedUser(response.response?.statusCode, urlOrSuffix: urlString)
            }

            self.checkResponseForSharevilleAlertMessage(response.response)

            if !hasResponseObject {
                if /*
let response = response,*/ (response.response?.statusCode)! < 400 && response.error == nil {
                    print("success for statuscode: \(response.response?.statusCode) url: \(urlString)")
                    success(nil)
                } else {
                    sendApiErrorWithUrlIfStatusCodeIsNot204(self.getUrlFromSuffix(urlString), statusCode: response.response?.statusCode)
                    print("fail for statuscode: \(response.response?.statusCode ?? nil) url: \(self.getUrlFromSuffix(urlString))")
                    print("request header")
                    print(response.request ?? "none"
                    failure(response.error)
                }
            }
        }
        .responseJSON { data in
            if hasResponseObject {
                if let value = data.result.value, data.response != nil && data.response!.statusCode < 400 && data.result.error == nil {
                    print("success for statuscode: \(data.response!.statusCode) url: \(urlString)")
                    success(value as AnyObject?)
                } else {
                    sendApiErrorWithUrlIfStatusCodeIsNot204(urlString, statusCode: data.response?.statusCode)
                    print("fail for statuscode: \(data.response?.statusCode) url: \(urlString)")
                    failure(data.result.error)
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: My guess? You are using default `(NS)URLSession` with default `(NS)URLSessionConfiguration`, which may refuser changing the headers for keys "Authorization", "Connection", "Host", "WWW-Authenticate". You may look there:https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#http-headers & https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#session-manager

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try with

> .validate()

.  in between request() and response() .  in your alamofire request call

```
Alamofire.request(urlString, method:method, parameters: nil, encoding: encoding, headers: authenticatedJsonHeaders)
        .validate().response {  //   }
```